# CheckBox doesn't change state

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewbinder

I have a:

```
public class MyList extends ListActivity {
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;
```

Binding to the `ListView` is done by a `ViewBinder`:

```
    simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, getData(path),
            R.layout.menu_row, new String[] { 
        ..., "checked" }, new int[] {..., R.id.checkBox1 });

    SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder viewBinder = new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                String textRepresentation) {
            if (view.getId() == R.id.checkBox1) {
                                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view;
                checkBox.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean((String) data));
```

My xml looks like this, `clickable` and `focusable` helps that the row behaves seen as one.

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
     />
```

I also have a:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
```

which interacts with the click event. This works good so far, my problem is 
when I click on a row, the `CheckBox` doesn't change its visual state. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `button.setChecked(true)` in you're onListItemClick ( or code to toggle back and forth using setChecked).

EDIT

Misunderstood your issue.  Have you told the adapter that the dataset has been changed?

Comment: who is button? 
what i have is
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
 
  CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        checkbox.setChecked(!checkbox.isChecked());

but it showns no effect

Comment: Sorry, meant checkbox.  Can you confirm the status is changing even if the graphic isn't?  Have you tried notifyDatasetChanged (I think I got that right, I:m on my phone and away from resources)

Comment: yes i call simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
that was the problem: it calls the getData method, which doesn't know of any check box changes. i commented it out, thanks your thoughts brought pointed me to the err

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to look into is a `CheckedTextView` which shows a check box and when a list item is clicked the check box changes

Comment: no i dont want to. my layout is much more complicated and there is no need for major changes. My feeling says there is only a small setting that fixes my problem